# how to remove a break in geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the code below, I have created my plot of interest. The only issue is the break between the brown line the rest of the four lines (Year=205). How can I solve this by joining the brown line to the other four lines?

Thanks,

Nader

```
UN_2010_plot <- ggplot()+
  geom_line(aes(x =Year, y =Population , group=Variant, colour = Variant), data = UN_2010)+

  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(x =Year+10, y = Population, colour = Variant, label = Variant, fontface = 'bold'), data = UN_2010 %>% 
                             
                             filter(Year == max(Year)),
                           segment.color = 'transparent',
                           direction         = "y",
                           size = 3,
                           box.padding = 0,
                           force = 0
  ) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        strip.background = element_rect(
          color="white", fill="white", size=1.5, linetype="solid"
        ))+
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1950,2100,10))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(10000,150000,10000))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(10000, 150000))+

  labs(
    x = NULL,
    y = "Population (thousands)",
    caption = (NULL),
    face = "bold"
  ) +
ggtitle("The 2010 Revision") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=0))
  

UN_2010_plot
```

[image]

Comment: The issue is not about plotting, the issue is about preparing your dataset. To connect the lines for the four population variants to the brown line you have to complete your dataset, i.e. for each of the variants you have to add an observation which corresponds to last data year (= 2010) of the brown line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stefan already mentioned. Here is the psuedo code that fixed your data which would connect the ending lines with starting line.

```
additional_data <- tibble(Year = rep(2010, 4), 
                          Population = rep(UN_2010$Population[Year == "2010"], 4),
                          Variant <- c("Low", "Medium", "Constant", "High"))

UN_2010_new <- bind_rows(UN_2010, additional_data) %>% arrange(Year, Variant)
```